# Excel Subtotal function is not creating a sum of the numbers in a table

Tags: excel, function, sum

I have a super simple table with a column called "Hours Book".

I'm trying to get the sum of the hours in this column, however none of the functions seem to be accomplishing that.

I've tried using both the sum and subtotal functions. Sum gives me 0 when used like:

`=SUM([Hours Booked])`

If I try subtotal with the 103 code (for count how many items are in the list), I get the expected 4.

`=SUBTOTAL(103,[Hours Booked])`

[image: Result of count code in subtotal formula]

However, when I try to use code 109 (to create a sum of the numbers), I still get 0.

`=SUBTOTAL(109,[Hours Booked])`

[image: Result of sum code in subtotal formula]

I've also tried referencing the table column from another sheet to verify that 'Hours Booked' actually works elsewhere.

I used:

`=EngagementList[Hours Booked]`

and got:

[image: List of hours from other table]

So, the table is working correctly.

I tried sorting the column and it seems to sort in alphabetical order, not number order. However, I've also verified that all columns are in a number format.

[image: Screenshot showing number format for cells]

Does anyone have any ideas why this isn't working? This seems like it should be dead simple, but it's been causing me grief for a while. It's vital to my workflow.

Comment: It doesn't looks like those are formatted as numbers, those are text also there is a space in beginning of each of those numbers. please check.

Comment: Mayukh, can you turn your comment into an answer please? That was the issue and I'd like to mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As OP mentioned above to post it as an answer hence updated here,

> It doesn't looks like those are formatted as numbers, those are text, also there is a space in beginning of each of those numbers. please check and it will work !

---